# Transfer from Washington National (DCA) to Dulles(IAD)

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer, iad, dca

I'm worried about the time between my connection flights.
I'll be flying from Rochester ROC to Washington DCA and then I'll have to change airport and go to IAD Dulles to grab my connection flight to London Heathrow on the 27th of December 2016.

So I'll be landing at 1:15pm in DCA and my flight to London is at 6pm from IAD.

What would be the easiest way to go to IAD airport ?

I'm really nervous to miss my flight and I could definitely use some advice from you guys

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

First, don't be nervous.  If it's already booked, there's no point in worrying.

So, it's a ~45 ride from DCA to IAD in 'average' conditions.  So, 4hrs 45min is plenty of time.

However, given the date, this itinerary is 'weather permitting' on both ends.

I would take Uber.  $30 maybe, give or take.